# Adding a Dependency Property To a Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, dependency-properties

I am trying to learn about Dependency Properties and attached Properties in wpf, and I was wandering If someone could explain to me how to add a DependencyProperty to a wpf Control. In my case I would like to add a Dependency Property to Datagrid, do you have to create a custom  wpf control to do this or can i simply add a dependency property to the wpf datagrids, how would I do this? I have been looking around and I believe it is possible but I am not exactly sure hw to achieve this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add code to a framework class.  If you want a Datagrid but with a dependency property, you'll have to inherit from Datagrid and declare the dependency property in your derived class.

Comment: Ok :) so does that mean I would have to create a custom control derived from Datagrid, and add that to xaml such as <local:myDatagrid ...> etc and would that work the same as the original datagrid but with my dependency included? Sorry if it seems a bit naive :(

Comment: Yes, that's a valid option.  You could define a custom control that inherits from Datagrid, and then your first course of business would be to define a dependency property on your new custom control.  From there, it would be accessed in the XAML as you've indicated, and you could use your newly defined dependency property from XAML as well.

Comment: What if the class you are inheriting from does not implement dependency object?